# Where is all my memory being used?

Tags: linux, memory, debian

I've got an HP Microserver with 4 gig, running a pretty minimal LXDE desktop right next to me. It's primarily a web and small VM server. It's using Debian 7.2 Stable.

```
# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3840       3262        577          0         19        238
-/+ buffers/cache:       3005        834
Swap:         7628         12       7616
```

What I gather from this is that this is not the usual problem that frightens people of disk caches growing large. If I force the caches to drop, it only frees 100 meg or so, so I don't think that's the problem here.

What i'm trying to find out is what's using the 3 gigabytes.

```
# cat /proc/meminfo 
MemTotal:        3932292 kB
MemFree:          919468 kB
Buffers:            2356 kB
Cached:            74220 kB
SwapCached:         1932 kB
Active:           201688 kB
Inactive:          44464 kB
Active(anon):     153004 kB
Inactive(anon):    24032 kB
Active(file):      48684 kB
Inactive(file):    20432 kB
Unevictable:          16 kB
Mlocked:              16 kB
SwapTotal:       7812088 kB
SwapFree:        7798840 kB
Dirty:                40 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:        167800 kB
Mapped:           362992 kB
Shmem:              7412 kB
Slab:              43164 kB
SReclaimable:      10728 kB
SUnreclaim:        32436 kB
KernelStack:        3688 kB
PageTables:        14072 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     9778232 kB
Committed_AS:    1364204 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:     2580308 kB
VmallocChunk:   34357040804 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:      124480 kB
DirectMap2M:     3938304 kB
DirectMap1G:           0 kB
```

Having a look at `/proc/meminfo`, adding up all of the Active/Inactive sections only comes out to about 1GB, leaving me with 2GB more unaccounted for. This also squares nicely with the output from `top` and where I should subjectively be considering what's running on the system right now.

Some other posts suggested looking at the `Slab:` number here, but that only is 43 megabytes.

Any idea where else I should be looking for this missing 2 gigabytes?

Comment: Can you post the output of freemem -a?

Comment: The output of `cat /proc/meminfo` wouldn't hurt either. As is you provide no real details so any answer would just be general information on what can consume memory on a Linux/Unix system.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae - No such command or such program in the repos. Updated the question.

Comment: You may wish to try (as sudo) the following commands: sync;  echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches ; free -m. The sync command forces writing out to disk everything pending in the buffers; the echo command will flush cached disk. This will leave only other allocations under the cachhe heading

Comment: @MariusMatutiae `If I force the caches to drop, it only frees 100 meg or so, so I don't think that's the problem here.`. That only clears the relatively small amount of data under the cache heading as stated in the question, it does not free up the unaccounted for two gigabytes.

Comment: There's always `top`.

Comment: @MartinSchröder The top count does not add up, hence my problem.

Answer (score 2):

you can see what's eating you memory with this [command](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/how-to-show-the-memory-usage-per-process-160181/).

`ps -e -orss=,args= | sort -b -k1,1n`

Answer (score 0):

If the machine you are having issues is VM, then you might be running into something called "Ballooning". Basically this is a way for the host system to apply memory pressure to the guest OS, consuming the guest’s memory allocation when other hosts start using a significant amount of memory.

http://www.vfrank.org/2013/09/18/understanding-vmware-ballooning/

If you are using VMware, run the command

```
vmware-toolbox-cmd stat balloon
```

This will show the amount of ballooned memory. I would venture to guess that this is where your 2 GB of memory is sitting and that this would be your answer to where your other memory is used. Which would be your VM host is using it.

Other sources: [Detect memory ballooning from within the affected VM](//serverfault.com/questions/660080/detect-memory-ballooning-from-within-the-affected-vm)

Turn off ballooned memory to validate the issue.

Unballooning memory: [“Unballooning” RAM that’s been ballooned by VMware](//serverfault.com/questions/528295/unballooning-ram-thats-been-ballooned-by-vmware)

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Comment: I added more to the answer to make it more explicit in answering his question. I feel that this is the answer to his question. He asked where his memory went. If my suspicion is correct that this is a VM guest (which he did state but was ambiguous), then the answer would be that his "VM Host is using it" (which I added to the answer). I gave a command for him to check the memory ballooning value and a method of turning off to confirm if he was using VMware (YMMV on other VM hosts). This to me directly answers his question.

Comment: Understood. But asking questions "Is the machine you are having issues with a VM?" should be done in comments not answers.

Answer (score -1):

With apologies to @Ereli

you can see what's eating you memory with this command.

`ps krss -e -orss=,args=`

where `krss` means to sort by resident set size (real memory used), `-e` means to show all processes and `-orss=,args=` means to print the rss and command arguments.

Another way to produce a very similar output, but on (e.g.) MacOS, might be

`ps mexOrss`

where `m` means sort by memory usage, `e` means to include other people's processes, `x` means to include processes without controlling terminals, and `Orss` means to add resident set size to the output.