# What's using my memory?

Tags: linux, memory

I'm trying to figure out what's using up the memory on my linux (ubuntu 20.04) server.

A little while after a reboot, htop is showing this:

[image: htop]

This suggests that 17 GB of memory is currently in use.  Before I rebooted, it was showing that as 29.6 GB and the computer was seeming sluggish.  The htop window is sorted by memory and the highest using process is using 0.6% of memory.

[Another question](https://superuser.com/questions/668705/where-is-all-my-memory-being-used) suggested using this command:

```
ps -e -orss=,args= | sort -b -k1,1n
```

The highest usage process reports 209596 kilobytes (?) of memory, so again a small proportion of the available RAM.

I tried a rather cryptic command to add up all the numbers in the first column reported by that `ps` command:

```
ps -e -orss=,args= | sort -b -k1,1n | sed 's/^ \+//' | cut -d \  -f 1 | sed '2,$s/$/+/' | sed '$s/$/p/' | dc
```

That reports total usage as 2965816 kilobytes (?), which (assuming my kilobytes assumption is correct) is less than 3 GB, so where's the other 14 GB going?

Can anyone help with this please?

Comment: Are you perhaps using ZFS?

Comment: @DanielB Yes (although not for / ) - is that causing me a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Yes - is that causing me a problem?

It’s not causing a problem. This is expected behavior. ZFS is originally not made for Linux. It has its own caching system (called ARC, Adaptive Replacement Cache). On Linux, the memory allocated to this cache is seen as “in use”, even though it will be freed when memory pressure rises, just like regular filesystem caching. The default maximum ARC size is 50% of physical memory.

In modern versions of `htop` (3+) you can turn on an ARC status display:

[image: htop 3 zfs status]

This screenshot is from a system with 8 GiB of memory.

Comment: If you want more info about what arc is doing check out https://cuddletech.com/2008/10/explore-your-zfs-adaptive-replacement-cache-arc/

Answer (score 2):

ZFS has a RAM based disk cache that is separate from the regular Linux disk cache. This has to do with ZFS's non-Linux origins. This ZFS memory cache is called the Adaptive Replacement Cache, or ARC. Due to this separation ZFS ARC shows up in Linux as 'used' memory, instead of 'cached', as you would expect for native filesystems, such as EXT4. This is the reason many people new to ZFS worry about RAM usage, but there is nothing to worry about. Unless you are dealing with deduplication (which you probably are not, and which you probably should not), memory is not that big a concern for ZFS, contrary to what many people will tell you.

You are seeing this disk cache (and thus memory) fill up because you are moving (which means reading) lots of data. The default memory limit for ARC is usually 50% of your ram, but is configurable through the zfs kernel module parameter 'zfs_arc_max', should you wish to set a maximum. If free memory ever becomes scarce, ZFS will release some of its ARC, just like Linux's regular disk cache would. Again, there is nothing to worry about; unused RAM is wasted RAM.

--[HenkAchterpaard](https://www.reddit.com/r/zfs/comments/g03dvs/comment/fn7lube/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

Comment: That's really useful thank you.  Is there any easy way to see the total RAM usage by everything except ZFS?

Comment: @Al. Probably. But I can't answer that one.